# How to iterate over strings in request object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

In Express, I'm trying to scan the POST requests and create the array `openingTimes`. And then create a MongoDB document , based on the inputs.

Following code snippet works fine but how can I make a loop instead of defining n days?

```
`module.exports.myController = function (request, response) {
    MongoDBModel.create({
        name: req.body.name,
 //I want to make a loop in here, so I dont have to define each day separately
        openingTimes: [{
            days: req.body.days1
            , opening: req.body.opening1
            , closing: req.body.closing1
            , closed: req.body.closed1
    }, {
            days: req.body.days2
            , opening: req.body.opening2
            , closing: req.body.closing2
            , closed: req.body.closed2
    }]
// catching errors
    }, function (err, location) {
        if (err) {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
            console.log("error is " + err);
        }
        else {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 201, location);
        }
    });
};`
```

Comment: Are there always exactly 2 objects in the `openingTimes` array?

Comment: Are the properties from the response named exactly `opening1, opening2` or different?

Comment: @Hydrothermal there can be any number of objects in the array. Indeed, I want to make a loop, to keep it flexible.

Comment: @Saravana currently I used Advanced REST Client (Chrome extension), and while putting data, I name them exactly as what is written there. For example, "days1 : Mon-Fri" , "days2: Sat", etc. But if I wanna make a loop, I'm not sure whether I can keep the current approach?

Answer (score 1):

You could create the array beforehand (or inline with an IIFE that returns the array).

```
var numDays = 7;
var openingTimes = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= numDays; i++) {
    openingTimes.push({
        days: reg.body['days' + i],
        opening: req.body['opening' + i],
        closing: req.body['closing' + i],
        closed: req.body['closed' + i]
    });
}
MongoDBModel.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    openingTimes: openingTimes
}, etc);
```

Or with ES6, you could be creative and make an IIFE with a generator function.

```
const numDays = 7;
MongoDBModel.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    openingTimes: [...function*() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= numDays; i++) {
            yield {
                days: reg.body['days' + i],
                opening: req.body['opening' + i],
                closing: req.body['closing' + i],
                closed: req.body['closed' + i]
            };
        }
    }()]
}, etc);
```

Comment: I tried the first answer and there is a big issue: It requires the user to specify 7 different days. But what I want is something to be flexible: if user inputs 3 days, then the function asks just for 3 days and then puts 3 days in the openingTimes array. 
If user puts two days, then fucntion asks just for two days and openingTimes array will have only two objects, etc.

Comment: You can use a variable in place of the number 7 for either solution.

Comment: and how that variable should be defined to work properly? If I just put a random variable, I dont think it works properly?

Comment: Have you tried something that didn't work? Just define a normal variable using `var`, `let`, or `const` and then use the variable in place of the number 7.

Comment: Yes I tried to put a "var x" instead of "7" but it didn't work: now, it doesnt push anything in the openingTimes array, so it will be returned empty, at the end. However, if instead of variable, I put a number (e.g. 3), then array will ask and will be populated with 3 objects. But as I said, I want a flexible solution in here. So, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: @MartinA I've added variables to my answer, but if you're having trouble with this subject, you should really be using a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work. It's true that I'm noob but I know this basic you just did :) And it doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, but "it doesn't work" doesn't tell me anything about what's going wrong. Do you have any errors? Are you sure the variable is being assigned to a number?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. You just put the number 7 into a variable and passed it in. Ofcourse it wont change anything :) So "it doesnt work" means that it now has same problem as before: it requires data for 7 different days and is not flexible if I put 3 or 4 days.

Comment: variable is being assigned but its always 7. I want something flexible. If I put 3 days, so it ask and put only 3 objects in the array, etc.